# Error in SQL Syntax? Have to Check Manual...right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=''' at line 11

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, manual

I've been trying to make a my settings page for the users of my website. When I open the mysettings.php page, the page successfully retrieves the info from the db. But when I click save, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=''' at line 11

I have made sure that all the data values are correct corresponding to the database field names. I am unaware as to why this is happening.

My code is:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE nb_user SET
        `first_name` = '$data[first_name]',
        `last_name` = '$data[last_name]',
        `country` = '$data[country]',
        `lang` = '$data[lang]',
        `tel` = '$data[tel]',
        `level` = '$data[level]',
        `p_desc` = '$data[p_desc]',
        `p_post` = '$data[p_post]',
        `p_progress` = '$data[p_progress]',
         WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'
        ") or die(mysql_error());

//header("Location: mysettings.php?msg=Profile Sucessfully saved");
$msg[] = "Profile Sucessfully saved";
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am logged on whilst this happens, and my user_id is 1.

Comment: Get rid of the comma before `where`

Comment: Brilliant - cant believe I left that in! Thanks!

Comment: yeah, did exactly this same mistake thanks for posting